# Android greenDAO Storing Floating point numbers wrong

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

Hi every one I am using green DAO library for creating and manipulating database and I have some fields in database like

```
     Float total;
```

when I am trying to insert values 25.4 it is storing 25.4099998474121

Afterwards when I retrieve data from database I am getting 25.4099998474121 and eventually all my calculations going wrong

please help me get out of this

Thank you

Comment: Can you show some code? It seems you stored 25.41

Answer (score 0):

While creating Sqlite table give the floating point field type as decimal(15,2). Here 2 specifies number of decimal points and 15 represents total number of digits allowed.

I tried with the following code and it works perfectly,

```
create table testing(numberField decimal(15,2))
insert into testing values(9999999999999.99)
```

but adding more values will round off.

In your case you need to insert,

```
insert into testing values(25.4)
```

this inserts the values as 25.4 exactly in sqlite database. If this doesn't work then your program is assigning extra values or rounding off.

Comment: i have specified the same but it has added 19 digits to the table

Comment: @SoftwareSainath I have updated the answer and try assigning to BigDecimal instead of Float while retrieving from database.